# onStateChange not firing from the script inject through content script[Chrome Extension]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api, content-script

I am trying to make a chrome extension,and for that I need to control the flash player on the YouTube by injecting my script through content script I am able to play ,pause and stop the video but the event listener does not fire. 
this is my code:

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
     currentVideo = document.getElementById("movie_player");
 window.onPlayerStateChange = function() {};
 currentVideo.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(e) {
    console.log('State is:', e.data);
});
```

}

**EDIT:** I found my mistake,apparently for flash function written inside the "addeventlistener" does not work.

```
     function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
         currentVideo = document.getElementById("movie_player");
     currentVideo.addEventListener("onStateChange", "StateChanged");
     }

     function StateChanged(e) {
         console.log('State is:', e);
     }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Comment: i came across that earlier but it does not solve my problem, i wrote the above function in the injected script as the answer suggests. but still the onstatechange is not getting fired